# Delete spaces in beginning of kill-ring in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to insert the contents of the kill-ring at the point using `(yank)`, however if there is white space in the beginning of the yanked text, it should be deleted before insertion.

How can this be done?

(I have looked at `save-excursion` and `re-search-backward` but could not get it to work)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
(defun my-yank ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start (point)))
    (call-interactively 'yank)
    (let ((end (point)))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char start)
        (delete-region (point)
                       (progn (skip-chars-forward " \t" end) (point)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution

```
(defun yank-no-spaces (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*P")
  (yank arg)
  (save-restriction
    (save-excursion
      (narrow-to-region (point) (mark))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (just-one-space 0))))
```